# can somebody give me an example of a translate api call using rest in android studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, android-studio-3.3

I am new to Android Programming, I barely know anything about android.

What I need to do is to translate a Text using Google Cloud Translate API for my Capstone Project. Is there any new methods, If there is, can somebody give me the exact sample code? The code below is 1.55.0 library.

```
        TranslateOptions options = TranslateOptions
                .newBuilder()
                .setApiKey(API_KEY)
                .build();

        Translate translate = options.getService();
        //gets the word to be translated
        final Translation translation =
                translate.translate(inputText.getText().toString().trim(), Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(setLanguage));

        textViewHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (outputText != null) {
                    outputText.setText(translation.getTranslatedText().trim());
                }
            }
        });
```

I expected the result to be a translated text, but instead it is reproducing an Error 400, bad Request which is Invalid Value.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `Google Translation API` in Android Studio project, first add in the `AndroidManifest.xml` the permission to access the internet. Because you are going to use the internet for the translation.

```
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Add some dependencies in the `build.gradle`. I came across with some minor issues in the gradle file, so I had to add few more stuff to fix them, the final result should look something like:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.59.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

In the `MainActivity`, in `onCreate(...)` class after `setContentView(...)` add:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

This will fix the error:

> ... Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ...

Finally make sure that you have:

- Enabled the `Translation API` in your project.
- The `setLanguage` variable that is used in `Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(setLanguage)` has the proper value for the targeted language.

I have tested this method and it worked for me.

Comment: Better is to run the code in background thread than changing threadpolicy. But thanks, helped